# Probability of at least t time units between occurences given intensity

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

It's been 15 years ago I did studies in statistics, so most of the knowledge is gone. I've looked up [Poisson's distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) but the tooth of time has taken a too large munch of my skills.

If I know that an alarm occurs 10 times a day, I have the average time between them to 144 minutes, which is my expected value. But what is the likelihood of the following events?

1. No alarm for 144 minutes
2. Precisely 1 alarm in 144 minutes
3. No alarm for 288 minutes
4. At least 3 alarms in 288 minutes

Please note that I'm not looking for the answer but rather a pointer on how to approach it. And in case this resembles school assignment and a lazy student, I'm not. However, it's a bit difficult to prove a non-fact. Perhaps a credential consisting of [my diploma work](https://www.chalmers.se/en/departments/math/centres/gmmc/Pages/master-theses.aspx) with a 10+ years worth of dust on it will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you assuming alarms are independent events with Poisson distribution?  If so, it straightforward.  Use $p_n=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda ^n}{n!}$. where $p_n$ is the probability of $n$ alarms in an interval where $\lambda=1$ for the first two questions and $=2$ for the second two.

Note for question 4, the answer requires $\sum_{n=3}^\infty p_n$. It is easier to get $1 - \sum_{n=0}^2 p_n$.

Comment: Is $k = n$ in the formula for $p_n$? If not, how do they relate and what does $k$ denote?

Comment: So, us tto verify I got it correctly, the two first are equal, i.e. 
$p_0 = p_1 = \frac{1}{e}$ and the third $p_0 = \frac{1}{2 e^2}$? The fourth I can get too but I'm too lazy to Latexify it here.

Comment: I corrected answer.  It was $n$ all the time.  $k$ was an error.  For 3, the answer is $\frac{1}{e^2}$.  For 4 you should have $1-\frac{5}{e^2}$

Comment: Oh, right. I confused what's being faculted and took $\lambda$ instead of $n$. I'm not as bright as I used to be. And I wasn't very so even before.   :)